# Nodejs non-async call to api in for loop

Tags: node.js

For a school assignment i must make a loop which does a api call and add those results to an array. how do i do this within Node JS?

Description of what my code does:
the function get all location of the pokemon.
when there are less then 10 pokemon in range of 1 kilometer
it add's te remaining pokemon. so you always have atleast 10 pokemon near.
during those adding it must get a random location of a random pokemon.
the random is done by a random integer (max 720) using the pokeapi(.co)
the end result will still be a list of all pokemon. inregardless if you need to add some or not.

the issue is that i don't know how i must do the api call for each 'toAdd. and add those to the array. as by default it's async.

Below i added my current code with few comments whats describes what i need.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var startDate = new Date();

  if (!req.query.lat || !req.query.lng) {
    res.status(400).json("Your location has not been included");
  }

  var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
  var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);

  location.count({}, function(err, count) {
    console.log(count);
  });

  location.find({}).exec(function(err, locations) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    var filteredlocations = [];
    locations.forEach(function(fetchedLocation) {
      distance = calcDistance(fetchedLocation.lat, fetchedLocation.lng, lat, lng);
      if (distance < 1000) {
        filteredlocations.push(fetchedLocation);
      }
    });

    if (filteredlocations.length < 10) {
      var toAdd = 10 - filteredlocations.length;
      console.log(toAdd);

      var newlocations = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < toAdd; i++) {
        var randomlocation = randomLocation(lat, lng);

        // random id = random
        var pokemon;
        var options = {
          host: 'pokeapi.co',
          port: 80,
          path: '/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=720',
          method: 'GET'
        };

        // This needs to fill the pokemon at a non-async method
        http.get(options, function(response) {
          var content = '';

          response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            content += chunk;
          });

          response.on('end', function() {
            var object = JSON.parse(content);

            pokemon = {
            {
              "pid": object.id,
              "name": object.name
            })
          });
        });

        var newlocation = //new location({
          {
            "lat": randomlocation.lat,
            "lng": randomlocation.lng,
            "pid": pokemon.pid,
            "name": pokemon.name,
          };

        newlocations.push(newlocation);
      }

      location.collection.insert(newlocations, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("err: " + err);
        } else {
          docs.ops.forEach(function(doc) {
            locations.push(doc);
          });
          return res.json(locations);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('niets toegevoegd');
      return res.json(dlocations);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this library and parallel operations. https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: @HarisHasan Any idea how to make that work. i believe you require to predefine the randomId's and then do a for loop on them but how to combine that with async.parallel();? can you explain it some more detailed?